# Middleware to make dictionary available to all views

Tags: django, django-views

I would appreciate if someone could help me by sharing a middleware code snippet that will allow me to create a dictionary that is accessible and updatable by all Django views.
{‘a’ : ‘a’, ‘b’ : ‘b’, etc.}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Normally the idea is to make a webserver quite *stateless*, so except for persistent datastructures like databases, or caches, like Redis, the idea is to *not* store things in a shared data structure.

Comment: Thanks Willem. The server is hosting a pool controller system, so it’s not exactly a straightforward setup. I could just store the variables in a database, but it seems overkill, what do you suggest?

Comment: well the first question is, why do you need such shared variable. By using a *global state*, you make the system harder to scale, maintain, test, etc. In fact *global state* (also sometimes named *God state*), is a (serious) antipattern: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil

Comment: I take your point Willem, but in this case Django is merely acting as a glorified GUI on a local network with probably a maximum of 2 users.